# ¿Cómo se podría realizar variables dummies teniendo en cuenta varias columnas?

Tags: python, pandas

estoy intentando pasar varias variables de un dataframe a dummies.

Una de las variables es música utilizada en una publicación de tiktok, donde no me ha sido complicado pasarla a dummie de la siguiente manera:

```
dummies_music = pd.get_dummies(df.music_title)
```

Pero estoy intentando pasar varias variables a la vez a dummies, ya que estas variables son hashtagh1, hashtag2... y hay valores repetidos entre estas dos variables, por lo que sólo me gustaría que se crease una dummie y tuviese en cuenta ese valor.

Adjunto imagen para facilitar la explicación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde sólo me gustaría que tuviese en cuenta una vez fcbarcelona, y así me dijese 1 en la publicación que se ha utilizado el hashtag y 0 en la que no, dando igual si es hashtag1 o 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicar `pandas.get_dummies` sobre todas las columnas que desees, esto obviamente generará columnas "duplicadas". Para unir todas las columnas relativas al mismo hashtag en una puedes simplemente agrupar en base a las columnas con `pandas.DataFrame.Groupby` y aplicar `any` sobre cada grupo.

`any` retornará `True` por cada fila si al menos una de las columnas es `True` y `False` si todas son `False`, es decir, equivaldría a aplicar *or* (`|`) de forma encadenada sobre la fila.

Primero un ejemplo simplificado:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                 
df = pd.DataFrame({                                                                                                                                  
    "hashtag1": ("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "B"),                                                                                                      
    "hashtag2": ("C", "B", "D", "B", "G", "A"),                                                                                                      
    "hashtag3": ("A", "E", "G", "F", "F", "D")}                                                                                                      
)
```

---

```
>>> df
                                                                  
  hashtag1 hashtag2 hashtag3                                                  
0        A        C        A                                                  
1        B        B        E                                                  
2        A        D        G                                                  
3        C        B        F                                                  
4        B        G        F                                                  
5        B        A        D
```

Ahora, aplicando lo comentado:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(                                                                                                                            
    df[["hashtag1", "hashtag2", "hashtag3"]],                                                                                            
    prefix="",                                                                                                                                       
    prefix_sep=""                                                                                                                                    
).T.groupby(level=0).any().T
```

tenemos:

```
>>> dummies 
                                                              
       A      B      C      D      E      F      G
0   True  False   True  False  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False   True  False  False
2   True  False  False   True  False  False   True
3  False   True   True  False  False   True  False
4  False   True  False  False  False   True   True
5   True   True  False   True  False  False  False
```

**Nota:** Aunque a día de hoy aún se puede usar `groupby(axis=1)` para agrupar sobre las columnas, el argumento está marcado como obsoleto desde Pandas 2.1 y será eliminado en el futuro, por eso hago uso del dataframe transpuesto.